# The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL server, I have a query like mentioned below:

```
SELECT B.Column_Value FROM GN_ELIXIR_CONFIG A, (SELECT Column_Value FROM Fn_String_Split_As_Rows (A.CONFIG_VALUE, ',' )) B
 WHERE A.CONFIG_NAME = 'CUSTOMER_CONTROL';
```

A.CONFIG_VALUE will return values like: 1000, 2000, 3000 ...

For Oracle, I use the same query, but with a slight change:

```
SELECT B.COLUMN_VALUE FROM GN_ELIXIR_CONFIG A, TABLE(FN_STRING_SPLIT_AS_ROWS(A.CONFIG_VALUE, ',')) B WHERE A.CONFIG_NAME = 'CUSTOMER_CONTROL';
```

Using the `FN_STRING_SPLIT_AS_ROWS` function, gives correct results. But the first query shows the following error:

```
The multi-part identifier "A.CONFIG_VALUE" could not be bound.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using APPLY in SQL Server:

```
SELECT B.COLUMN_VALUE FROM GN_ELIXIR_CONFIG A 
CROSS APPLY FN_STRING_SPLIT_AS_ROWS(A.CONFIG_VALUE, ',')) B 
WHERE A.CONFIG_NAME = 'CUSTOMER_CONTROL';
```